# How do i access a database using the returned results of a table?

Tags: mysql

```
create table a.a {
   db varchar(255)
} 

//first record of a.a is db = b

create table b.a {
   id varchar(255)
}
```

mysql to run:

```
use concat((select * from a.a limit 1),".a"); select * from a;
```

How can i achieve the above? Using the returned results of one table to access another database without doing round trips to mysql connection.

Comment: That isn't MySQL syntax for `CREATE TABLE`. The columns should be in `()` not `{}`.

Comment: You can't use variables for database, table, and column names in SQL. You'll need to write a stored procedure that uses `PREPARE` to create dynamic SQL.

Comment: I've seen some use "case" kind of statement to achieve this.
Is there any alternative to what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic SQL requires using [`PREPARE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html) in a stored procedure.

```
SET @sql = (SELECT CONCAT('SELECT * FROM `', a.a, '`')
             FROM a
             LIMIT 1);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

It's generally considered best to avoid designing your database so that it requires this. Don't spread the data among multiple tables with the same structure, use a single table and add another column to distinguish the records.